# Material design icons like "\f222" altered when shared across linux and Windows environments

Tags: linux, windows, git, encoding, utf-8

When I am working on the same repo with a colleague using Linux, while developing on Windows on my side, we always have conflicts with assets being minified.

It's with the material design icon library where the before elements contain code like content: "\f222";

If I grunt on my side and git push this, it translates into a different code on Linux environments. The same if my team does it on Linux and I pull their updates.

How can I make sure this does not happen?

It's only the case for this library; everything else works fine (using phpstorm for coding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you and your colleague on Windows have your local config `core.autocrlf` set to false.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Any other value for that setting would automatically convert eol (end-of-line character) for *all* files including ones which should be kept unchanged, always.